# Basic database on OS X?

Tags: osx, database

I have simple needs.

I am playing Elder Scrolls Online on Xbox One and on PC I could add various addons that kept track of what my different characters had in their inventory. Since the shared bank space isn't infinite, I could offload items from the bank onto a character and using an addon easily find out if I had a particular item, how many I had of it, and which other character(s) had them.

On Xbox One addons are not allowed/available/possible.

As such I have created a simple Excel spreadsheet to keep track of this but it would be far better to have a simple database with some lookup fields.

So I was wondering if there was a basic database application for OS X available?

Requirements:

- Be able to quickly find rows through a search function
- Have lookup fields (for instance for character name, item category)
- Have numeric fields (for number of items located on various characters)

It does not need to be a client against an existing SQL database, like SQLite, MySql, SQL Server, or any other client, it can be completely proprietary.

It does not need synchronization capabilities, if the database lives on my MacBook Pro that is fine. Dropbox-type synchronization is a bonus, but not a requirement at all.

It does not need any sort of programmability, nor SQL searching. Basically, if I can just add the various records and set up their relationship using forms, that is more than enough.

Basically, it can be really basic. Preferably it is also cheap though it does not have to be free.

I've used google to see what kind of options I have but invariably I end up finding either FileMaker Pro (or a similar one) for $300+ or a client against a full blown SQL type database.

Comment: Can make a list of the tables and fields you will track, with *brief* description and data type? You should make that list for yourself anyways, plus it may help us answer your Question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like possibly what you are looking for is [Symphytum](https://giowck.github.io/symphytum/).

[image: Screenshot]

It seems to check a lot of your boxes in terms of features you are looking for. It is cheap (free and open source), works on OS X (as well as other platforms), has search capabilities and different kind of fields, uses SQLite in the backend, and provides sync via DropBox.

Some of its advertised features include:

> - Fields are not just text. Design your input forms with support for different data types: text, numeric, date, progress, image, file list, checkbox, combobox, etc.
> - Two Views On The Same Data. Use the form view for structured data input and representation, use the table-like view for searching, sorting and comparing.
> - Integrated Cloud Sync. Using Symphytum across multiple computers is a joy. Your data is always automatically synchronized everywhere. Drivers for cloud services such as Dropbox are included.
> - Sync Conflict Management. Symphytum manages synchronization conflicts for you. While only one session with write access is allowed at the same time, other computers may access the database in read-only mode during an open session.
> - Date Reminder. Date fields keep you informed on tasks, appointments or birthdays, if requested. All Reminders, once triggered, are listed in one place.

Answer (score 0):

## Query Spreadsheets

Without more information, my first thought is to stick with spreadsheet. Some spreadsheet apps have a query feature, such as [LibreOffice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) and MS Excel (not sure about Numbers.app).

## LibreOffice Base

My second thought is to look at the database feature in LibreOffice, [Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/). I've not used that feature myself, but I’m guessing it might fit your needs well. Base can act as a front-end to database engines but it also comes with an engine embedded. LibreOffice is free-of-cost and open-source.

## 4D

My third thought is [4D](http://www.4D.com). A professional software development tool for building integrated database-backed apps. Like FileMaker on steroids. Fairly easy to get started. A commercial product but they used to have deals for education (don't know about now), if you are a student.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a simple Database Application for OSX, then I would recommend DB Browser for SQLite

**[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)** ([Open Source](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser))

> **What it is**
>
> DB Browser for SQLite is a high quality, visual, open source tool to
>   create, design, and edit database files compatible with SQLite.
>
> It is for users and developers wanting to create databases, search,
>   and edit data. It uses a familiar spreadsheet-like interface, and you
>   don't need to learn complicated SQL commands.
>
> Controls and wizards are available for users to:
>
> - Create and compact database files
> - Create, define, modify and delete tables
> - Create, define and delete indexes
> - Browse, edit, add and delete records
> - Search records
> - Import and export records as text
> - Import and export tables from/to CSV files
> - Import and export databases from/to SQL dump files
> - Issue SQL queries and inspect the results
> - Examine a log of all SQL commands issued by the application
>
> [image: SQLite DB Browser User Interface]